# Issues with CSV after scraping from HTML Page

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

My code is working fine but i am not sure why when i tried to output to csv. there are twice the amount of lines when i used "print".

Somehow i cant seem to decipher where is the extra row coming from.

Here is my code while saving to csv

```
url1 = 'https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Set_Card_Lists:Deck_Build_Pack:_Mystic_Fighters_(OCG-JP)'
output_file1_2 = "DBMF - CardList - tr2.csv" #change this to your own file output

def OutputHTMLFileSummary2(url,html_tag,output_file):
    array = []
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
    f = csv.writer(open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8"))
    links = soup.find_all(html_tag)

    counter = 0.0
    for link in links:
        counter += 1
        if (counter/2) != 0.0:
            array.append([f.text.strip().replace("\xa0\n\t", "") for f in link.find_all("td")])
            print(counter)
        else:
            pass
    print(array)
    for i in range(len(array)):
        f.writerow([array[i]])
OutputHTMLFileSummary2(url1,"tr",output_file6)

file = open(output_file6, encoding="utf-8")
reader = csv.reader(file)
lines= len(list(reader))
print(lines)
```

[The output in csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGorb.png)

Comment: what are you trying to do with the counter and counter/2 ??  You should not be testing float numbers for equality.  Are you trying to skip even numbers or something?

Comment: ignore the counters for now.. initially i wanted to use it to count the rows and if the rows hit an empty row, i will skip it but noticed i dont need to do that. i didnt remove that line of code (it can be removed)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work OK for me.  I made a couple tweaks to printouts, but they are same size.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
import csv

url1 = 'https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Set_Card_Lists:Deck_Build_Pack:_Mystic_Fighters_(OCG-JP)'
output_file = "DBMF - CardList - tr2.csv" #change this to your own file output

def OutputHTMLFileSummary2(url,html_tag,output_file):
    array = []
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
    with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as src:
        f = csv.writer(src)
        links = soup.find_all(html_tag)

        counter = 0.0
        for link in links:
            counter += 1
            if (counter/2) != 0.0:   # <---- do NOT do this...
                array.append([f.text.strip().replace("\xa0\n\t", "") for f in link.find_all("td")])
                print(counter)
            else:
                pass
        for idx, item in enumerate(array):
            print(f'{idx}: {item}')
        #print(array)
        for i in range(len(array)):
            f.writerow([array[i]])

OutputHTMLFileSummary2(url1,"tr",output_file)

file = open(output_file, encoding="utf-8")
reader = csv.reader(file)
#lines= len(list(reader))
print('\nFrom the file...\n')
for idx, item in enumerate(reader):
    print(f'{idx}: {item}')
file.close()
```